# Terrible Eclipse (3.5) - problem with "Install new software"

Tags: eclipse

I want to install additional software for Eclipse (I use 3.5 because 3.6 is not yet for Scala and Android).

Problem is:

- The downloads / installations are INSANELY slow, I didn't get past 5% on the ADT plugin (for example) in one hour - same for everything else I tried
- Firefox (no other software so far, IE works fine, etc...) is slowed down when it comes to Internet connectivity as long as "install new software" is running

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit here on a quadcore machine with 4 GB of RAM and an 8 MBit / sec DSL.

Is this a known issue, are there any fixes or will I have to stop considering developing for Android phones?

And yes, I disabled everything - firewall, Skype, etc...

Nothing helped.

JDK installed is 6u21, latest release (installed it today).

Comment: I successfully installed ADT into eclipse helios(3.6). But not sure Scala.

Comment: There is also a version of the Scala IDE for Eclipse 3.6 installable from `http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-helios-2.8.0.final`

Answer (score 2):

Try to uncheck the option 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' when installing ADT. But you must install all plug-ins required by ADT firstly, such as GEF.

Answer (score 0):

That 6u21 may be your problem, depending on how recently you downloaded it (and, if from a mirror, how up to date the mirror is). They changed "Sun Microsystems, Inc" to "Oracle", and Eclipse was relying on that string for resolution of a bug:

http://m.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/oracle-rebrands-java-breaks-eclipse/2012

From the article: "If you downloaded Java for Windows 32-bit or 64-bit recently, be sure you have the 1.6.0_21-b07 version and not b06."